# How to get the OnAppointmentAttendeesChanged LaunchEvent

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, outlook-calendar, officedev

I want to get the Appointment Attendee change, Time change event in outlook calendar.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/outlook/autolaunch.md I have referred this document.
I'm able to get the OnNewMessageCompose, OnNewAppointmentOrganizer event. But unable to get the Preview events.

I have integrated my app in microsoft 365 admin center.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/main/Samples/outlook-tag-external I have checked this sample project
OnMessageRecipientsChanged is working fine. I tried for OnAppointmentAttendeesChanged event. Unable to get that.

Is this possible to get the OnAppointmentAttendeesChanged, OnAppointmentTimeChanged event ?

Answer (score 0):

At present the MSDN page says that these preview events are supported on the web and on Windows.

To preview these events:

For Outlook on the web:

- Configure targeted release on your Microsoft 365 tenant.
- Reference the beta library on the CDN (`https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js`). The type definition file for TypeScript compilation and IntelliSense is found at the CDN and DefinitelyTyped. You can install these types with `npm install --save-dev @types/office-js-preview`.

For Outlook on Windows:

- The minimum required build is 16.0.14026.20000. Join the Office Insider program for access to Office beta builds.
- Configure the registry. Outlook includes a local copy of the production and beta versions of Office.js instead of loading from the CDN. By default, the local production copy of the API is referenced. To switch to the local beta copy of the Outlook JavaScript APIs, you need to add this registry entry, otherwise beta APIs may not be found.
- Create the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\WebExt\Developer`.

Add an entry named `EnableBetaAPIsInJavaScript` and set the value to 1. The following image shows what the registry should look like.

See [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) for more information.

Comment: Raji does this solve your issue? (are you on OWA or Outlook Win32 Desktop?)