# Outlook calendar event cancel

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2007

In outlook Calendar cancel any event , how to get this cancel event data in my outlook add ins code , it is possible or not , please help me

Example :
In outlook calendar event edit the attendees i am getting edited details using "onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler"  this handler but i am not able to get a cancel event data

Comment: You may want to refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784526/how-to-get-the-onappointmentattendeeschanged-launchevent

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish with this event? This event cannot be canceled. Also what platform are you experiencing issues with? OWA/Win32/Mac/ etc.

Comment: Are you interested in handling the `ItemSend` event in Outlook?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT , In outlook cancel any event , that cancel event values want to trigger in my outlook add ins , in this issue i am facing in is IOS platform , any handler is there for this

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support your scenario for add-ins on Outlook cancel event scenario. You can use this link to suggest a feature or provide feedback: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11