# Forwarding / Cancelling event javascript callback

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are trying to develop a outlook addin for new outlook and testing using Outlook 16.75.2 on Mac desktop app.

We have "OnMessageSend" / "OnAppointmentSend" working to get javascript callbacks when a mail is sent/replied/forwarded and appointment is created.

But when we forward the meeting invite or cancel the meeting, we dont have a Event type to receive javascript callback.
I tried all the event types listed here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest

Sample events from manifest.xml

`

```
        <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewAppointmentOrganizer" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageAttachmentsChanged" FunctionName="handleAttachMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentAttachmentsChanged" FunctionName="handleAttachMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageRecipientsChanged" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentAttendeesChanged" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentTimeChanged" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentRecurrenceChanged" FunctionName="handleSendMail"  SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnInfoBarDismissClicked" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentSend" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageCompose" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentOrganizer" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageFromChanged" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentFromChanged" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>

        <LaunchEvent Type="OnSensitivityLabelChanged" FunctionName="handleSendMail" SendMode="SoftBlock"/>`
```

Any help if I am missing something or the functionality is not supported at all ?

According to below link, Cancel is not supported. How can we support forward invite ?
[Outlook calendar event cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68823696/outlook-calendar-event-cancel)

have callback for appointment forward/cancel

Answer (score 0):

We do not support add-ins in the meeting forward scenario by design in Outlook Mac. This is the reason you do not see any events in this case.
You can add a new feature request for this.
We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.